# Lumen App Deployed on GAE is unable to connect to DB in cloud-sql

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, lumen, app-engine-flexible

I developed an API in Lumen and deployed it on GAE. I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) tutorial for that purpose. It worked fine until the deployment of API but the problem came when I tried to access the DB that is on the cloud-sql instance. I am unable to access the DB in the way described in the above mentioned tutorial. Then I tried the different solution and none of them work. At-last just for test purpose I added the Instances IP address (where the GAE is deployed) in the authorized list of the cloud-sql instance and its working now. But this is a temporary solution as Instances are deployed on VM's and their IP address can change at anytime that will break the connection between GAE and cloud-sql. Any solution or suggestion will be appreciated. 
Although I have tried by changing my App.yaml multiple ways but still I have given it below:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  #APP_ENV: production
  APP_DEBUG: true
  #QUEUE_DRIVER: sync
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: 32 char key
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  #APP_TIMEZONE: UTC
  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
  DB_DATABASE: dbname
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: pass
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/Instance Connection Name"
  MYSQL_DSN: "mysql:unix_socket=/Instance Connection Name;dbname=dbname"
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass

beta_settings:
    # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
    # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
    cloud_sql_instances: "Instance Connection Name"
```

Comment: what errors are you seeing? what are you executing when getting these errors? could you share some logs?

Comment: Could you also share your app.yaml file? (careful not to expose any sensitive data)

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio I am getting "[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" error. Moreover, I have added my app.yaml, kindly have a look.

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio as I mentioned in the question that when I add the ip addresses of the App Engine instances in the authorised list of cloud-sql instance and access the database through cloud-sql instance ip address then i am able to access the database but this is not the right way because it can break anytime.

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to deploy. I was able to deploy only by deleting the env variable CACHE_DRIVER. The code was downloaded from the Laravel documentation page, so I'm not sure what that variable does or if it's gonna break something.

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio thanks for reply. I will try this and will let you know that either it solved my problem or not.

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio I tried your solution but its not working.